# How can I do debugging with vCloud using visual studio? how can I attach my vCloud machine?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I have one `.exe` windows app, so I am just installing my `.exe` in vCloud which I created windows 10 machine in vCloud. Normally it is running successfully, so right now my `WindowsApp` crashing in vCloud Windows 10 machine, so how can I Debug that machine and how to configure in my VS2012.

Thanks for help.

Comment: i tried attaching my vCloud machine to my visual studio..which is getting problem. Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: and i tied with with vCloud external IP which is able to access vCloud machine through mstsc like remote debugging.